# Is it okay, to put meshes inside each other without connecting them?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices, faces

Excuse my English.
So, im modeling an assault rifle and i was thinking about if its okay to disconnect the highlighted mesh(picture below) from the weapon and just move it a bit inside the weapon to achieve a lower polygon count and more clear mesh.

I want to export this model into Unreal(if this information is important)[image][image]

Comment: It is okay. Designers use this method usually.